# Can computer sticks run ROS? (intel compute stick)

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there.

I need some very portable hardware like a computer stick such as an intel compute stick or an Asus vivostick for a project. The system needs to be x86 architecture so I cannot make use of an ARM system such as the Raspberry Pi.
From some google searches I have seen that it is possible to install ubuntu on an Intel Compute Stick. Do any of you have any experience or knowledge about running linux and ROS on one of these computer sticks?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320419/can-computer-sticks-run-ros?-(intel-compute-stick)/) by [albert02](https://answers.ros.org/users/40737/albert02/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot really install things on the Intel Compute Stick like you're thinking, its not a computer, its just an additional [thing] to offload computations to, where you talk to it over their SDK, which handles all the Stick communication and transfers.

When we talk about using it with ROS, it's really more that there's a ROS wrapped version of their SDK you can use (in their case, its a service server you can query images for detection/classification that Intel suppors). In general though you just need to learn their SDK and use it in your ROS code.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [albert02](https://answers.ros.org/users/40737/albert02/) on 2019-04-08**:
Interesting I wasn't aware that stick pc's are not full pc's. Thanks.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-04-08**:
No problem, if that answers your question can you mark it as answered? That removes it from the unanswered questions queue.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer above, however is not correct. Intel compute stick is a full x86 pc, with either celeron or even core m cpu and countless people have installed ubuntu on it. The compute stick and neural compute stick are totally two different things.

---

Originally posted by [asydynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/41129/asydynamics/) with karma: 11 on 2019-04-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-05-14**:
Hi, you are correct. I have mixed up the Neural compute stick. Admittedly, that naming nomenclature is a mixup-prone.